# What is the correct way to do a "dotnet publish" on Project1 before building Project2

Tags: c#, msbuild, post-build-event

I have a solution with 2 projects. One is a VSIX and the other is a .NET Core 2.1 Console app.

The projects do not directly depend on each other, but I need to ensure that VSIX embeds a fresh version of all output files from the other project as it is built, because it will need them at runtime.

Putting the following in the post-build event of the VSIX project used to work:

```
cd "$(SolutionDir)MyCoreConsoleApp"
dotnet publish --configuration $(Configuration)
```

It's worth mentioning that there were some strange problems with this setup in the beginning, though... The console app could be built fine if done by issuing rebuild of the project from Solution Explorer directly. Issuing `dotnet publish` from VSIX's before-build, on the other hand, would fail with errors, basically saying the build system could not locate all the required files.

After a lot of effort, I determined that the problem was the fact that console app used Fody Costura at the time. After removing this dependency, `dotnet publish` started working without any problems.

Fast forward to yesterday... I added a dependency on MSBuild Community Tasks to console app project, because I wanted to use the Zip task to embed a zipped copy of some content files as EmbeddedResource. I've added a custom Target to the csproj and confirmed that it worked correctly when doing a direct build of the project or issuing `dotnet publish` from command line. In case it matters, the Target itself looks like this:

```
<Target Name="ZipAndEmbedWwwRoot" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <CreateItem Include="wwwroot\**\*">
    <Output ItemName="ZipFiles" TaskParameter="Include" />
  </CreateItem>
  <Zip ZipFileName="$(IntermediateOutputPath)wwwroot.zip" WorkingDirectory="wwwroot" Files="@(ZipFiles)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)wwwroot.zip">
      <LogicalName>wwwroot.zip</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

But now building the VSIX started failing again. The error is:

> The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Zip" task could not be loaded from the
>   assembly
>   C:\Users\MyUserName\.nuget\packages\msbuildtasks\1.5.0.235\build\..\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
>    declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

As soon as I remove the custom Target, things start working again.

I'm starting to think I'm probably missing something when calling `dotnet publish` on a project, which has additional msbuild dependencies. This was probably the reason why Fody Costura didn't work, either.

So the question is, how *should* I be doing this, then?

Comment: I think your question is only related to the zip task and not to your publishing setup? if so, please narrow down the question on the problem only

Comment: @MartinUllrich: The immediate goal is invoking the Zip task, yes. But since I've had similar problems with Fody Costura before that, I felt I might mention everything in order not to overlook a possible connection between the parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community Zip task is quite old and no longer works with recent versions of MSBuild or the cross-platform `dotnet` CLI.

However, VS 2017 15.8 and the CLI 2.1.400 introduced the built-in [`ZipDirectory` task](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/50639058f947ef3b21075cb110f06913124d2942/src/Tasks/ZipDirectory.cs) you could use instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware of these things. Will give it a try and report back. Thanks!